# PCA between matlab PLS toolsbox and R

Tags: pca

I am recently starting doing PCA with some pyrosequencing community result (which basically tell how many species in different samples). I am having two choices on software - PLS tools in matlab or package vegan in R.

In R , I input my normallised (relative abundance) file and use rda in package vegan:

```
pca<-rda(myfile)
biplot(pca)
```

I noticed that PLS tools give you option to choose mean centering, with that option, the PCA graph looks totally different between software. I am wondering whether this mean centering option make any different? 
I read some website that mentioned we should always do the mean centering for PCA, is there any way I can do mean centering in R as well? Or does the function rda in R did the mean centering by itself?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Mean centring is done automatically and always in `rda()` function in vegan. The vegan function does not offer you any other option. Neither do standard R functions `prcomp` (recommended) nor `princomp` (not recommended).